# What is the name of the Jenkins Slave Service on a Windows Node?

Tags: jenkins, phabricator

Jenkins Setup Description:

1. Jenkins Master is installed on a Linux Box.
2. There is a Windows Slave and the Launch Method is configured as 'Let Jenkins control this Windows Slave as a Windows Service'

In the above setup, I see that the node is connected and I m able to run builds on the windows box as well,So the slave service is running for sure. But what is the name of the Jenkins Slave Service running on this Windows Machine ? Google says its supposed to be "Jenkins Slave". I m currently on Jenkins ver. 1.617.

Answer (score 1):

That's the display name, and it's correct.

The unfriendly service name is **jenkinsslave-C__Jenkins**.